# bone rig is not working properly

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, bones

so I have been following a tutorial which is I m trying to learn more about rigging , as if its the only thing I Did not learn much about , so I decided to actually follow a tutorial to learn more about , as you can see on the picture whenever I try To Move the back foot bone there is a weird glitching happening on the foot like its the upside down foot is kind of having some sort of glitch or its not moving as it should , when I want to move it back , the foot should move only but does not really glitch the whole foot , I m still new at rigging so I m wondering how to fix this issue , I went to some weight paint and tried to add and sub but I m still confused here , even though I followed the tutorial at some point , I Will upload the blend file as if its hard to notice , I Hope I can find a fix for that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZQNI.png)

The animation rig tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMQ56rQuC6s&ab_channel=PIXXO3D
the character weight paint tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JF4sIMEfqzE&t=371s&ab_channel=PIXXO3D

The blend file  : here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you see some vertices of the left leg are part of some right vertex groups and vice-versa, this should not be the case:

[image]

This has probably happened because you have inverted normals, you need to switch to *Edit* mode, select all and recalculate the normals (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>). Parent again and it will work fine without any manual correction.

[image]